# Angular Js parse deeper JSON file

Tags: json, angular

I am trying to parse an array inside an object. I tried to map the result to get the array but could not reach to the point of the array.

My JSON looks like this.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "projectName": "Opera house",
  "projectDescription": "This image was taken during my first photography course.",
  "thumbnailImageName": "1.JPG",
  "projectDetails": {
    "id": 1,
    "relatedPhotos": [
      "1.JPG",
      "2.JPG",
      "3.JPG"
    ],
    "location": "Sydney",
    "scope": "Learn basic of photography",
    "description": "Some description"
  },
  "favouriteProject": true
}
```

And I am mapping the HTTP response from a server like this.

```
this.projectService.getProjectDetailsByProjectName(projectName).subscribe(res => 
      {
        Object.keys(res).map(key => {
          this.projectDetails = res[key];
        })

    });
```

The above mapping gives me the projectDetails object but cannot access the array inside it. While accessing the array, I get output three times. Two times undefined and finally the actual value. Can anyone guide me how to parse the above JSON file properly?

Thank you very much..

************Edited code****************
My code to get the http response and parse each object is as follows:

```
getSelectedProjectWithDetails(){
    const projectName:string = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("project-name");
    this.projectService.getProjectDetailsByProjectName(projectName).subscribe(res => {
      // console.log(res.relatedPhotos);
      Object.keys(res).map( (key, value) => {
        this.projectDetails = res[key];
        console.log(this.projectDetails["relatedPhotos"])
      })
    })
  }
```

I have project interface as

```
export interface project{
    id:number;
    projectName: string;
    projectDescription: string;
    favouriteProject: boolean;
    thumbnailImageName: string;

    projectDetail: projectDetail;
}
```

and projectDetails interface as:

```
export interface projectDetail{
    id: number;
    relatedPhotos: String [];
    location: string;
    scope: string;
    description: string;
}
```

and http get request is

```
 getProjectDetailsByProjectName(projectName: String): Observable<project>{
    return this.http.get<project>("http://127.0.0.1:8080/project/"+projectName);
  }
```

[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: You can use `res.json()` to convert entire result into JSON.

Comment: Cannot do. It says json property does not exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use **map()** to transform HttpResponse body to JSON using **json()** method. Since response contains body, headers etc. **json()** can be used to only parse body.

Please look into below code to understand the same.

```
this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
  .map(response => response.json())
.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

To know more, please refer [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data)

Comment: does not work. Cannot apply json to the type of Observable. Isn't the above response is in JSON already?

Comment: I am getting undefined while accessing the relatedPhotos array. I think its due to asynchronous nature of HTTp call. Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate you can user `JSON.parse(res);` after you have mapped your response from observable.

like this

```
   Object.keys(res).map(key => {
      JSON.parse(res);
      this.projectDetails = res[key];
    })
```

However I am using res.json();

```
addNewProduct(data: any): Observable<string> {
    return this._http.post(this.addNewProdUrl, data).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Not sure what is the issue with your res.

Comment: I have access to projectDetails object. But I cannot get the relatedPhotos array inside that object using projectDetails.relatedProjects

Comment: your code `this.projectDetails = res[key];` what is the value u are getting after this line execution in this.projectDetails?

Comment: I get all the data of projectDetails key. But when i do console.log(projectDetails.relatedPhotos) I get 3 different data.    1. Undefined    ***************        2. ["1.JPG", "2.JPG", "3.JPG"]   *********************3. Undefined.

Comment: ` Object.keys(res).map(key => {
      JSON.parse(res);
      this.projectDetails = res[key];
    })`

what is the response being sent in this code because if u are sending whole json you shared above it will not properly match your requirement

Comment: `return this._http.get(this.updateProdDescUrl).map(res => res.json());`

i tried this with your json in angular service and in component after subscribe 

`response => {
            Object.keys(response).map(key => {
      this.projectDetails = response[key];
    });
    
    console.log(this.projectDetails["relatedPhotos"]);`

i got the object `(3) ["1.JPG", "2.JPG", "3.JPG"]`

Comment: Can you please see the edited section. I have attached the screenshot as well. Due to the undefined value, I am not getting anything in the html for loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166658/discussion-between-bikram-and-sagar-kharab).

Comment: `Object.keys(res).map( (key, value) => {
        this.projectDetails = res[key];
        console.log(this.projectDetails["relatedPhotos"])
      })`

As i suspected. You are using this on main json you need to first get the object of project details by 

`response => {
               Object.keys(response).map(key => {
  this.mainObject= response[key];
 });
this.projectDetails = this.mainObject["projectDetails"];
this.relatedPhotos=this.projectDetails["relatedPhotos"];
}`

Comment: Not working. But solved by using  this.projectService.getProjectDetailsByProjectName(projectName).subscribe(res => {
      // console.log(res.relatedPhotos);
      Object.keys(res).map( (key, value) => {
        this.projectDetails = res[key];

        if(this.projectDetails.relatedPhotos ){
          this.relatedPhotos = this.projectDetails.relatedPhotos; 
        }
        
      })
    })